# iPad Side Bar Interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to create an interface similar to the app Instapaper.  The works just like a navigation bar except its on the left hand side.

I'm having an issue creating this interface.  Any ideas on how to do this type of interface.  I was thinking of a window with a view controller split up with two different views.

Any ideas, suggestions, or even a tutorial?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mine (in Instapaper) is just one big view controller with a sidebar view that toggles the contents of the larger view manually. It's not too bad in my case, since it can only have two states -- grid or browser -- that simply switch which data is shown in the grid/browser.

If you can require iOS 5 as the minimum, you can use some of the new child-view-controller mechanics, but I couldn't yet.

Comment: Brilliance.  Excellent app by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start with and try [this](https://github.com/bjhomer/HSImageSidebarView) library out

Comment: Thanks, this is very similar to what I wanted to achieve.